# Can mt.xe update a manifest embedded in middle (not near the end) of an exe?

Tags: manifest, visual-foxpro, mt

I'm trying to update the manifest included in a Visual FoxPro app with some registry free COM entries. A compiled FoxPro exe appears to contain a VFP runtime along with with some string resources and a default manifest, as well as the pre-compiled app code appended to the end of the exe. When using `mt.exe -manifest app.manifest -outputresource:app.exe;#1` the resulting exe is truncated. The manifest is placed at the end of the exe and all the pre-compiled app code is simply removed. Is there a way to update the embedded manifest using mt.exe without removing the app code from the exe, which is normally appended after the manifest?

I've found two alternatives that do NOT work for me. I'm forced to compile the exe with VFP 8, due to code incompatibility with VFP 9.

1. An article written by Rick Strahl https://www.west-wind.com/wconnect/weblog/ShowEntry.blog?id=890 that assumes the app is compiled using FoxPro 9 SP 2, which isn't an option for me.
2. A project hook class that assumes the app is compiled in VFP 9 https://www.sweetpotatosoftware.com/blog/index.php/2009/08/03/apply-application-manifest-at-compile-time-with-projecthook/ This is kind of close, but compiling with VFP 9 is not an option for me.

I'm hoping mt.exe provides a better alternative than building my own app to update the manifest in a VFP 8 exe.

Comment: I don't have an answer for your mt question, but I am very curious why you might be forced to compile in VFP 8? (a version which I skipped sort of).

Comment: @cetin That's a great question. The primary app that our shop produces started out in 1984 as a dBase II app. It's been ported from that to FoxPlus, FoxPro, all the way to VFP 8. When we tried to port to VFP 9, we were initially spooked by performance metrics, then later by very old code that needed more love to port. After 15 years, we're still more interested in pumping out features than porting the code. _shrug_

Comment: You summarized my foxpro life in computing, starting with dBase II, foxbase, foxplus ... VFP9 :) After all it is your code, you know it best. Sorry I couldn't help.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this?

Comment: @CarbonMan (1/2) I figured out a workaround. From what I can tell, the data after the manifest is just your precompiled program. So, I built an app that stores those precompiled bytes to a separate file, truncated the exe so that the manifest is at the end of the file, and ran mt.exe. Then I appended the precompiled bytes back onto the exe. It worked well for me, but figuring out which bytes to save off wasn't straightforward.

Comment: @CarbonMan (2/2) I used the source for the project hook mentioned to figure out how to find those bytes, but that link is now dead. I no longer have access to the source code for the app I wrote, either. I do recall that the exe can contain multiple sections of precompiled code. Sort of like (or maybe exactly like) app files that are appended to the end of the exe. The last few bytes of each section define how many bytes it is. Each section starts with a 2-byte moniker. So, you can read the exe from the last byte backwards and save off each section until you no longer find that 2-byte moniker.

Answer (score 0):

[resourceHacker](http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/) does a good job of modifying a vfp exe. I have replaced and deleted manifests in vfp8 executables.
vfp9 seemed to include the ability to embed custom manifests during the build process.